# Which type of operations are not confiables to be made on-chain?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, security

I already saw a bunch of people talking that some operations are not safe to be made on-chain so it's better to receive this information as a function parameter from an off-chain source, but I did not find an explication of which type of operation is not safe to be made on-chain, and should be made externally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally all informations that the blockchain cannot retrieve from real world. In common use, these are operations in which you should use off-chain third parties:

- Financial Data Requests: when you want to have the price about
  specific asset, you must to retrieve it off-chain;
- Randomness: When you want to generate a randon number for use it in your smart contract, you must to generate it off-chain. This  because smart contract are deterministic and someone study your smart contract can use this knowledge to exploit your application;
- Cross-chain requests;

More information [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-do-i-get-off-chain-data-from-a-smart-contract-blockchain-oracles-explained-aee391d15938).